# How to reposition images in JavaScript and how to rearrange images randomly?

Tags: javascript

If you click on the Change Location button, a prompt will pop up.

For example, if you enter 1-4, position 1 and 4 must be changed.

Also, if you press the 'Shuffle' button, the 4 photos have to be rearranged at random.

Here is the code that I made

[image][image]

Comment: you'll need to figure out how to add your code to the question

Comment: You need to edit and copy/paste not upload, upload is only for images.

Comment: You need to use `document.getElementById('image1')` the ids have image not just numbers like `id="1"`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I need to learn how to add code..

Answer (score 0):

you select all images, you can use querySelectorAll:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="image"]');
```

then you filter images based on prompt value:

```
var filter = [];
for (var i in images) {
   if (array.indexOf(i)) {
      filter.push(images[i]);
   }
}
```

then `filter` variable will hold DOM nodes for your images now you can randomize them (you can search how to randomize an array on SO).

```
var shuffle = shuffle_array(filter);
```

Then you can iterate over shuffle get style data `node.style.cssText` and then set it other node, you can iterate over two arrays one `filter` and `shuffle`.